# get variable from another class SpriteKit

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a variable set in my LevelOne.Swift:

```
var isLevelCompleted = false
```

I also have a function in my LevelOne.Swift. When it is called it changes the value to true:

```
func levelOneComplete(){
        isLevelCompleted = true

    }
```

I want to access this variable from a different swift class. How can I go about doing this? I tried several different methods but I can't seem to get it to recognize the variable.

Comment: What about making LevelOne class a singleton?

Comment: Have you tried making it universal? By this I mean put it outside skscene. For example             Import SpriteKit                                                          Var isLevelCompleted

Comment: What if the two classes are in two different swift files. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to make the variable global, so it's not inside any class at all. This may not always be the most safe way but it does work most of the time and is really easy. In the example beneath I have two classes which can both `set` and `get` the `isLevelCompleted` variable. (The classes obviously don't have to be UIViewController).

```
var isLevelCompleted: Bool!

class LevelOne : UIViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad() //Just an example
       isLevelCompleted = true

    }
}
class LevelTwo : UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      print(isLevelCompleted) // prints "true"
   }
}
```

Comment: What if the two classes are in two different swift files. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes that doesn't matter at all. (That's only the representation, to the computer there is no difference)